# Syntax highlighting changes after save in Vim

Tags: vim, markdown

I have installed [Markdown syntax plugin](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=1242).

When I'm on a new buffer not associated with any file, and paste the source portion of the site http://rosylilly.github.com/markdown.html into it, the colors appear nicely as it should for the markdown syntax.

However, after saving the file, the colors change. Any idea how I can fix this?

Comment: Could you _show us_ what it looks like _after saving_? The colors _change_ -- into what?

Answer (score 1):

Can you, before *and* after saving do

```
:verbose set filetype
:verbose set
```

<sub>Tip: use `:redir > file.txt` to capture the output so you won't have to copy/paste which can be difficult with gvim - for command output</sub>

You could also look at the autocommands when saving:

```
:verbose au BufWrite
:verbose au BufWritePre
:verbose au BufWritePost
```

This would serve to discover what plugin/script is causing the highlighting to go haywire.